# phpmailer not sending mail to gmail

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

I have a email program that runs from a cron that was working, and now it doesn't. Well, it still works, but it doesn't send any emails to gmail. I have filters setup in gmail's filters to send all emails from: 'my domain' to my inbox instead of the spam folder, but now they don't even go to the spam folder. It works with yahoo and textfree.us.

Here is the code:

```
$alerttarget = $usersemail;
$subject = "A bill is OVERDUE!";
$body = "You have an overdue bill, in the amount of $" . $amount . ".";
$from = $userId . date("YmdHis") . $billdetailId . "b@mydomain.com";

sendemail($alerttarget, $body, $from, $subject);

function sendemail($target, $body, $from, $subject)
{

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $email = $target;

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "localhost"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SetFrom($from, "my domain");
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from, "my domain");

    $mail->Subject    = $subject;

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $address = $email;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "me");


    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
```

I recently bought a new domain, and set the host to point to my ip address. I did this with godaddy's DNS manager. But, I only set the host to point to my ip address; nothing else. It stopped working, however, before I did all of this.

Comment: If this is hosted on your server did you check the mail log to verify that the server is sending out the messages?  If this is not on a server you have access to can you give more details about the hosting setup?

Comment: This is on my server and I can send email to other domains (i.e. yahoo.com, textfree.us).

Comment: What do the mail logs look like when you try to send?